# check if a network shared directory is in use

Tags: c#, directory, rename, move

My program make a zip file from a shared folder and copy this file to another location. 
Then I want to rename the original folder to "//original folder" + "_ziped"
But I can't do that if anybody is using any file on that folder or subfolders. I need to check before make the zip file if is there anybody in. Then I try to move to temp name and move to the original name.

```
try
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo("OriginalPath");
    dir.MoveTo("OriginalPath" + "_temp");
    dir.MoveTo("OriginalPath");
}
```

this works if the OriginalPath is in my computer, bu if  is in a shared folder do this:

```
 dir.MoveTo("OriginalPath" + "_temp");
```

and throw exception on:

```
 dir.MoveTo("OriginalPath");
```

I don't know why.

What is the correct way to check if it is in use?

Comment: What exception?

Comment: IO.Exception.  Access Denied (if i debug step by step not ever throw the exception) thanks